# traffic light progam using timer

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a simple traffic light simulation and I want it to be the case that when I press a button the sequence starts and every five seconds there is a colour change. I am using three panels for this.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Panel1.BackColor = Color.White
```

I know that this is how you would set it up for 1 event, however in my program the top panel starts off as red and the other two white, and after five seconds I want the second panel to change to yellow, and after five more seconds I want the first two panels to turn white and the third one to turn green. How would I achieve this? Also how do I start the process when a button is clicked?

Comment: Simply setup your timer to count from 1 to 3. Create a method that takes an integer as an input and call it from your timer each time you increment it. It will be easier if you get your logic out of the timer tick event and into a subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

So what I did was make an Enum called LightStatus that would make the currently lit light variable (lsCurrent) more readable in the code.

When the form loads, it sets the timer properties with an interval of 5000 ms so it will trigger the Elapsed event every 5 seconds.  I add a handler to the Elapsed event of the trigger to call the ChangeLight Sub.  It also passes Red into SetLight so that Red is lit up right away.

When the button is clicked, it starts the timer.  When the Elapsed event is triggered, it runs ChangeLight which changes lsCurrent from Green to Yellow, Yellow to Red, or Red to Green and calls SetLight which sets the Panel BackColor based on lsCurrent.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim tmrLight As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer
Dim lsCurrent As LightStatus = LightStatus.Red

Private Enum LightStatus
    Red = 1
    Yellow = 2
    Green = 3
End Enum

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    tmrLight.Interval = 5000
    AddHandler tmrLight.Elapsed, AddressOf ChangeLight
    SetLight(LightStatus.Red)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    tmrLight.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub ChangeLight()

    Select Case lsCurrent

        Case LightStatus.Red

            lsCurrent = LightStatus.Green

        Case LightStatus.Yellow

            lsCurrent = LightStatus.Red

        Case LightStatus.Green

            lsCurrent = LightStatus.Yellow

        Case Else

            lsCurrent = LightStatus.Red

    End Select

    SetLight(lsCurrent)

End Sub

Private Sub SetLight(LightColor As LightStatus)

    Select Case LightColor

        Case LightStatus.Red

            Me.pnlRed.BackColor = Color.Red
            Me.pnlYellow.BackColor = Color.White
            Me.pnlGreen.BackColor = Color.White

        Case LightStatus.Yellow

            Me.pnlRed.BackColor = Color.White
            Me.pnlYellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.pnlGreen.BackColor = Color.White

        Case LightStatus.Green

            Me.pnlRed.BackColor = Color.White
            Me.pnlYellow.BackColor = Color.White
            Me.pnlGreen.BackColor = Color.Green

        Case Else

            Me.pnlRed.BackColor = Color.Red
            Me.pnlYellow.BackColor = Color.White
            Me.pnlGreen.BackColor = Color.White

    End Select

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This will work, though you should explain your logic not just dump a block of code as an answer.